# Java- Finding maximum number in second set of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

How do I find the maximum number of all the dp[1] values? In this example below, answer is 21,  as I only look at the second number of the set. Currently using a for loop, but looking for something efficient.

```
int[][] dp = new int[30][2];
```

> {5,9}, {31,7}, {4, 21}, {24, 16}

This question is slightly different [Java- Finding maximum number in a 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035161/java-finding-maximum-number-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: correct @Abra 9,7,21,16

Comment: A `for` loop should be super efficient, though perhaps a bit more verbose (and less potentially parallelizable) than other approaches.  For instance, you're unlikely to find a solution that's more efficient than `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; for (int[] arr : dp) { max = Math.max(arr[1], max); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved in a straightforward manner using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```java
int[][] dp = {{5,9}, {6,7}, {4, 21}, {7, 12}};

int max = Arrays.stream(dp).mapToInt(a -> a[1]).max().orElseThrow();
```

This streams over the outer array, maps each inner array to the second element of that array, then returns the maximum element of those mapped values.

### Detailed breakdown

1. [`Arrays.stream(dp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)) - Returns a [`Stream<int[]>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of the array's elements.
2. [`mapToInt(a -> a[1])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) - Applies a [`ToIntFunction<int[]>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) to each element of the `Stream<int[]>`, returning an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) of those results.  This uses function `a -> a[1]`, which takes an array and returns the element at index 1.
3. [`max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#max()) - Returns the maximum `int` in the `IntStream` as an `OptionalInt`.  This `OptionalInt` will contain the max value (unless the stream is empty, in which case it'll be an empty `OptionalInt`).
4. [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalInt.html#orElseThrow()) - Returns the `int` value in the `OptionalInt`, or throws [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) if the `OptionalInt` is empty.